# make linkbutton inside a datagrid non clickable on certain conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datagrid with linkbutton inside it.

```
<asp:DataGrid id="listDataGrid" Runat="server">
                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Item Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:LinkButton id="lbItemName" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return false;" />
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>


In c#

foreach (DataGridItem dataGridItem in listDataGrid.Items)
            {
LinkButton lbItemName;
lbItemName = (LinkButton)dataGridItem.Cells[1].FindControl("lbItemName");
if (display == false)
                {
                    lbItemName.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration: none;cursor: default;");
                    lbItemName.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
                }

}
```

But link button still works as a clickable link. I want to make it to show as text.

THanks

Comment: Since it's a server control can you do `lbItemName.Enabled= false"`? Also try adding `!important` after each of the styles.

Comment: What event are you looping through DataGrid in?

Comment: I tried enabled="false" also, but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a literal tag that is not visible. If you do not want it to be a hyperlink make the lblitemname.visble = false and make the literal tag visible